# Change toggle direction

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap 4 Alpha 5 and I have the default navbar with a toggle menu. This is great, but i'm wondering if it's possible to change the direction of the toggle. Now the menu is getting visible from top to bottom. I would like change this to "left to right", so it looks like the menu is floating from the left side of the screen.

If possible, I prefer not to use third party libs.

Thank you.